# Where do trigonometric functions belong in the order of operations?

Tags: trigonometry, notation

I am wondering, where do trigonometric functions ($\sin, \cos$...) belong in the order of operations?

It is obvious when evaluating $\sin(43+47)$, we add 43 and 47 together to get 90, and sine it to get 1. But if we add some more operations, like this: $2+7(\sin(8+37)+2)-2\cos(30)$, what do we do first?

Comment: Apply B.O.D.M.A.S. since sine function is a bracket and then a function, it pretty much sums your required answer

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi What is the "O" in BODMAS? I know it's "Of", but what does this "Of" mean?

Comment: "Operations" is what I learned the O to represent... it being a generic placeholder for many other named functions or operations... including but not limited to a function like $\sin(x)$ or exponentiation, or floor functions, or the multitude of other functions which you will encounter throughout your studies.  Generally, you will see such functions have parentheses holding their inputs or will know when parentheses are implied at which point you generally just compute things "inside out" simplifying the simpler expressions inside of parentheses first whenever possible.

Comment: So... for your example, we started with $2+7(\sin(8+37)+2)-2\cos(30)$ I would first simplify the parentheses inside of the sine to get $2+7(\sin(45)+2)-2\cos(30)$.  Next, I would evaluate the functions.  Assuming you intended the arguments to be in degrees (*implied by the nice values of $30$ and $45$*) rather than radians (*be aware that radians are far more common in calculus and above*) this continues as $2+7(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+2)-2\cdot \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ at which point we are now to just adding and multiplying numbers as usual.

Comment: As a nitpick., you should get into the habit of labeling inputs to a trig function with degrees to emphasize that they are not radians (*which are commonly left unlabeled*).  It is better to write `\sin(90^\circ)` giving $\sin(90^\circ)$ which evaluates to $1$ so that it is not confused with $\sin(90~\color{grey}{\text{radians}})$ which evaluates to approximately $0.894$

Comment: $\cos 2x$ to mean $\cos(2x)$ is accepted to lighten writing, but don't use the first in a CAS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigonometric Functions (And Functions In General) Aren't Considered As Operators, But As Functions Instead, So, Technically Speaking, They Can't Belong In The Order Of Operation (A.K.A. BODMAS/PEDMAS/BIDMAS). BUT, If We Would Count Them As Operators, Then They Would Be Computed In The Very Beginning Of A Equation.

That Is, For Example, If We Have A Equation $(7 + 9)^2/sin(\pi/2) - 2 * 8$, Then We Firstly Compute $sin(\pi/2)$, Which Will Be 1. Then We Compute $(7+9)$ (That's 16) And Square The Result (Which Will Be 256). Now We Compute $256/1$, Which Is Going To Be 256. We Now Multiply 2 By 8, Which Gets Us 16. And, Finally, We Subtract 256 By 16, Giving Us 240.

**Summary**: The Order Of Operations (Including Functions) Is... Functions. Brackets. Orders. Multiplication And Division. Addition And Subtraction. (Or Simply FBODMAS, Though Some Might Say FPEMDAS Or FBIDMAS Depending On Where You Live.)

Comment: But your explanation seems to always reply on using parentheses to enclose the argument of a trig function, which isn't always the practice. For sin 2x, we don't interpret it as (sin 2)x.